# How do I force batch to use nojs?

Tags: 6, batch-operations

I am having trouble using batch. The problem is that on the client website, there is an error in the jquery file in the jquery_update module and I am not allowed to change this because I am just building a custom module for them. So, JS won't run and batch is locked. 
I want to force batch to use do_nojs such that the page is reloaded using http meta. Is there any solution I can use for that?

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the inverse problem using Pressflow. From that I have learned:

1. The js version runs if and only if the has_js cookie is set. If you are able to clear that cookie (and keep it away), you will be able to run batch.
2. When the cookie is not set, there is a query parameter in the meta refresh tag, namely op=do_nojs (and not op=do as is normal). If it is a batch you are trying to run and one for which you know the batch id, you may be able to force a nojs solution.

Based on that, if you are only having problems with tunning batches yourself, the simple solution is to disable js in your browser before starting the batch operation.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this cookie but I really can't clear it at the right time so the batch won't consider it.

Comment: You don't mention your use case so it's hard to be specific. For example: are you trying to get some specific batch jobs run yourself or are you trying to get it working for a larger audience?

Comment: In fact I have a problem with the jquery_upgrade version on the targer website and the batch progress bar doesn't move due to js errors. So I wanted to use the no js version to display correctly th progress bar